# How do I loop through column names and make one ggplot scatterplot combining all columns

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, knitr

I have several sweeped measurements placed in columns in a dataframe.
Sometimes the sweep is i.e. 40 ticks, but mostly they are 256 ticks (8bit).
Columns are always arranged in the correct order.

My script gets configured from an imported excel file telling it what plots to make and collect into a word doc or pdf using knitr.

Now I would like to plot several cols in a dataframe and combine them on the all in one plot.

Example:

col 77 is x

col 338 to 368 is y

col 76 is used for colorgrading the dots.

Example df:

```
temperature_set  VDD_set  RCAL01  RCAL02 RCAL03
             15      3.3     -97     -98   -103
             15      3.3     -97     -98   -103
             15      3.3     -97     -98   -103
             15      3.3     -97     -98   -103
             15      3.3     -97     -98   -103
             15      3.3     -97     -98   -103
```

This example results in a plot including the first and last iteration only:

```
myplot <- qplot(df[[77]], 
                df[[338]])
for(i in 339:368){
  myplot <- myplot + geom_point(aes(x = df[[77]],
                                    y = df[[i]], 
                                    color = df[[76]]))
}
print(myplot)
```

This example only plots the last iteration:

```
myplot <- ggplot(df)
for(i in 338:368){
  myplot <- myplot + geom_point(aes(x = df[[77]],
                                    y = df[[i]], 
                                    color = df[[76]]))
}
print(myplot)
```

This work, but coding is not pretty, scalable or practical:

```
ggplot(df, aes(df[[77]], df[,338])) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,339], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,340], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,341], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,342], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,343], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,344], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,345], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,346], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,347], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,348], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,349], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,350], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,351], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,352], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,353], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,354], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,355], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,356], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,357], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,358], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,359], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,360], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,361], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,362], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,363], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,364], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,365], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,366], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,367], color = df[,76] )) +
  geom_point(aes(x=df[[77]],y=df[,368], color = df[,76] ))
```

This kinda works, but the plot does not expand its axis and ggplot is more stylish :o)

```
plot(Data_Char[[77]], Data_Char[,338])
for(i in 338:368){
  points(Data_Char[[77]], Data_Char[,i])
}
```

Do I have to rearrange data before plotting with ggplot or is there a solution without?

Comment: It's hard to answer you question without data. I'd suggest posting a `dput(df)` here. Also it looks like you're not keeping the same structure between your `for loop` and your plot with each `geom_point` manually typed. Should the `for loop` have commas before the columns in it? Something like: `...y = df[[,i]], 
                                    color = df[[,76]]))`

Comment: Try `myplot <<- ...` ... though bringing your data into another format (long) would be easier. Than you could automatically map different colors for all columns. If you provide a `dput(head(yourData))` we can help your properly.

Comment: It would be best to reshape your data to long format using `reshape2` package (for example) and then use an additional `group =` option with just one `geom_point`. Without reshaping your data, I would use `aes_string` instead of `aes` and make `ggplot(df, aes_string(x = names(df)[77], color = names(df)[76]))` to initiate and add `geom_point(aes_string(y = names(df)[i]))` to your plot in the loop.

Comment: Martin Dabbel Ju Smelter: Tried to make a small example df, the real df is huge.

Comment: Choubi: Will try aes_string if that doesn't work, I will reshape data :o)

Comment: Ok, tried reshape2 melt function. It is really neat! if no one else comes up with an elegant solution, I think that should be the answer :o)

Comment: You might be able to work with this, though I dont have your data, so I have not run it yet.... `x <- 339:368,
  apply_fun_n_times <- function(input, fun, n){
      for(i in 1:n){
        input <- fun(input)
      }
      return(input)
    },
    plotfunc <- function(x){myplot + geom_point(aes(x = df[[77]],
                            y = df[[x]], 
                            color = df[[76]]))},
    for(i in x){
    finalplot <- apply_fun_n_times(myplot,plotfunc(i), 1)
    }
    ,print(finalplot)`

Answer (score 0):

Best option, reformat the data from wide to long using `tidyr::gather`.  Here is an example using the `mpg` data set from the `ggplot2` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

#' reshape the data from wide to long.  Example the mpg data set from ggplot2

mpg 
# # A tibble: 234 × 11
#    manufacturer      model displ  year   cyl      trans   drv   cty   hwy    fl   class
#           <chr>      <chr> <dbl> <int> <int>      <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <chr>   <chr>
# 1          audi         a4   1.8  1999     4   auto(l5)     f    18    29     p compact
# 2          audi         a4   1.8  1999     4 manual(m5)     f    21    29     p compact
# 3          audi         a4   2.0  2008     4 manual(m6)     f    20    31     p compact
# 4          audi         a4   2.0  2008     4   auto(av)     f    21    30     p compact
# 5          audi         a4   2.8  1999     6   auto(l5)     f    16    26     p compact
# 6          audi         a4   2.8  1999     6 manual(m5)     f    18    26     p compact
# 7          audi         a4   3.1  2008     6   auto(av)     f    18    27     p compact
# 8          audi a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 manual(m5)     4    18    26     p compact
# 9          audi a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4   auto(l5)     4    16    25     p compact
# 10         audi a4 quattro   2.0  2008     4 manual(m6)     4    20    28     p compact
# # ... with 224 more rows


# let column 1 (manufacturer) be the x value, 
#     columns 3, 5, 8, and 9 be different y values (displ, cyl, cty, hwy)
# and column 6 be the coloring variable (trans)

mpg_long <-
  tidyr::gather(mpg, key = response, value = value, displ, cyl, cty, hwy)

mpg_long
# # A tibble: 936 × 9
#    manufacturer      model  year      trans   drv    fl   class response value
#           <chr>      <chr> <int>      <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
# 1          audi         a4  1999   auto(l5)     f     p compact    displ   1.8
# 2          audi         a4  1999 manual(m5)     f     p compact    displ   1.8
# 3          audi         a4  2008 manual(m6)     f     p compact    displ   2.0
# 4          audi         a4  2008   auto(av)     f     p compact    displ   2.0
# 5          audi         a4  1999   auto(l5)     f     p compact    displ   2.8
# 6          audi         a4  1999 manual(m5)     f     p compact    displ   2.8
# 7          audi         a4  2008   auto(av)     f     p compact    displ   3.1
# 8          audi a4 quattro  1999 manual(m5)     4     p compact    displ   1.8
# 9          audi a4 quattro  1999   auto(l5)     4     p compact    displ   1.8
# 10         audi a4 quattro  2008 manual(m6)     4     p compact    displ   2.0
# # ... with 926 more rows


# Graphic
ggplot(mpg_long) +
  aes(x = manufacturer, y = value, color = trans) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

```
# Use the shape aesthetic to show which response is which
last_plot() + aes(shape = response)
```

[image]